# Warnings when using the Javacard Converter

Tags: javacard

When using the javacard converter I keep getting the following errors:

> Java Card 2.1.2 Class File Converter (version 1.2)
> Copyright (c) 2001 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved.
>
> warning:
> warning:
> warning:
>
> conversion completed with 0 errors and 3 warnings.
> Java Card 2.1.2 CAP File Builder (version 0.55)
> Copyright (c) 2001 Sun Microsystems, Inc. All rights reserved.

So what are these warnings? I am using the Sim Application Toolkit which produces these results, when using the UICC toolkit I only get 1 warning. Why do I get these warnings?

Comment: Well, that is extremely difficult to tell without the actual warnings. Have you generated the class files using the correct JDK (the one mentioned in the Java Card toolkit)?

Comment: Yes, when compiling I have the following switches: 
-target 1.1 -source 1.3 
Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that should be correct. If I'm not mistaken, those are the settings required by the Java Card toolkit. The question is more how to display the actual warnings. I presume you have also tried the JDK that was recommended by the Java Card toolkit? Have you specified the -v in the command line arguments? Please display the command line you used!

Comment: I've added the verbose switch yet it still only says Warning. It appears though after the line that parses sim tool kit .exp files. I'm sorry I can't display the command used exactly.